# Como Restar valores de 2 select condicionados

Tags: mysql, sql

necesito restar el campo Total de 2 select.
las consultas son las siguientes:

```
Select Establecimiento, Mes, Sum(Col1+col4+col7+col10) AS Total
From Datos
Where Codigo in ('A1234k','a1212V','d1451k')
Group By Establecimiento, Mes

menos

Select Establecimiento, Mes, Sum(Col2+col3+col11+col15) AS Total
From Datos
Where Codigo in ('C1234k','C1212V','C1451k')
Group By Establecimiento, Mes
```

Para la resta, el establecimiento y mes deben ser coincidentes.
lo trate de agrupar en una sola tabla nueva con un UNION pero no me resulto.

Comment: utiliza variables para almacenar los resultados de cada uno de los querys, y luego haces la operacion entre variables.

Comment: ¿Qué resultados esperas si hubiera grupos distintos de `Establecimiento` y/o `Mes`? [Ejemplo de las diferentes respuestas con datos en ese supuesto](https://dbfiddle.uk/ejSEfYnJ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una alternativa usando un solo `SELECT` y condicionando la suma para lograr la resta que buscas:

```
Select  Establecimiento, 
        Mes, 
        Sum(CASE WHEN Codigo in ('C1234k','C1212V','C1451k') 
                 THEN (Col2+col3+col11+col15) * -1
                 ELSE Col1+col4+col7+col10
            END
        ) AS Total
        From Datos
        Where Codigo in ('A1234k','a1212V','d1451k', 'C1234k','C1212V','C1451k')
        Group By Establecimiento, Mes
```

Comment: Patricio, los resultados son algo disparatados si agregamos valores distintos en `Establecimiento` y en `Mes`. [Ver fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hgB43oDZ) (tu consulta está al final). Puede que haya un error en el planteamiento inicial de OP y que ese sea el problema principal en este caso.

Comment: @A.Cedano  no lo creo, el OP dice "Para la resta, el establecimiento y mes deben ser coincidentes", en tu consulta estas aplicando el select de la resta sin tener en cuenta esta definición

Comment: Patricio, para mí, el planteamiento sigue siendo confuso.

Comment: Puede ser, aunque a mi no me lo pareció, por eso respondí

Answer (score 2):

Pues combinas ambas subconsultas por `Establecimiento` y `Mes`, no con `UNION` sino con `JOIN`, y restas las columnas de totales, tal que así:

```
SELECT Establecimiento, Mes, Total1 - Total2 Total
  FROM (
    Select Establecimiento, Mes, Sum(Col1+col4+col7+col10) AS Total1
    From Datos
    Where Codigo in ('A1234k','a1212V','d1451k')
    Group By Establecimiento, Mes
  ) c1 JOIN (
    Select Establecimiento, Mes, Sum(Col2+col3+col11+col15) AS Total2
    From Datos
    Where Codigo in ('C1234k','C1212V','C1451k')
    Group By Establecimiento, Mes
  ) c2 USING(Establecimiento, Mes);
```

Si dudas entre `UNION` y `JOIN` es que aún tienes que afianzar conceptos de fusión de tablas. Piensa que `UNION` pega una tabla encima de la otra, mientras que `JOIN` las pega una al lado de la otra.

Para realizar esa operación con `UNION`, que también se podría, puedes proceder así:

```
SELECT Establecimiento, Mes, SUM(Total) Total
  FROM (
    Select Establecimiento, Mes, Sum(Col1+col4+col7+col10) AS Total
    From Datos
    Where Codigo in ('A1234k','a1212V','d1451k')
    Group By Establecimiento, Mes
    UNION ALL
    Select Establecimiento, Mes, -Sum(Col2+col3+col11+col15) AS Total
    From Datos
    Where Codigo in ('C1234k','C1212V','C1451k')
    Group By Establecimiento, Mes
  ) c1
  GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Esto debe ser `UNION ALL` en vez de `UNION [DISTINCT]`.

Comment: Corregido. Gracias. También ya sería mala suerte que coincidieran ambos resultados, pero sí, tienes razón.

Comment: Si agregamos grupos distintos en `Establecimiento` y en `Mes` esto no funciona. [Ver fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ejSEfYnJ) (al final la consulta de Patricio y las dos tuyas). Creo que hay un error en el planteamiento inicial de OP, con respecto a los grupos, o falta aclarar que se trata de una consulta donde siempre los grupos de `Establecimiento` y `Mes` serán iguales o qué resultados se esperan cuando ocurra lo contrario.

Answer (score 0):

Tú puedes escribir dos sub-consultas y luego restar el total de ambos grupos.

Algo así:

```
SELECT 
  `a`.`Total` AS `totalA`, 
  `b`.`Total` AS `totalB`, 
  `a`.`Total`-`b`.`Total` AS `resta`
FROM
  (SELECT 
      `Establecimiento`, 
      `Mes`, 
      SUM(`Col1`+`Col4`+`Col7`+`Col10`) AS `Total`
    FROM `Datos`
    WHERE `Codigo` IN ('A1234k','a1212V','d1451k')
    GROUP BY `Establecimiento`, `Mes`) AS `a`,
  
  (SELECT 
      `Establecimiento`, 
      `Mes`, 
      SUM(`Col2`+`Col3`+`Col11`+`Col15`) AS `Total`
    FROM `Datos`
    WHERE `Codigo` IN ('C1234k','C1212V','C1451k')
    GROUP BY `Establecimiento`, `Mes`) AS `b`;
```

No obstante, tu código, o el propósito que pretendes aquí no parece ser estándar. Fíjate más abajo, en los resultados del fiddle, que se van a generar varias filas cuando haya diferentes valores en `Establecimiento` o en `Mes` a causa del `GROUP BY`.

Aquí un fiddle completo:

```
CREATE TABLE Datos (
    Codigo VARCHAR(25),
    Establecimiento VARCHAR(255),
    Mes INT,
    Col1 INT,
    Col4 INT,
    Col7 INT,
    Col10 INT,
    Col2 INT,
    Col3 INT,
    Col11 INT,
    Col15 INT
);
```

```
INSERT INTO Datos VALUES
  ('A1234k','E1',1,10,2,5,1,1,1,1,1),
  ('a1212V','E1',1,20,3,6,1,1,1,1,1),
  ('d1451k','E2',1,30,4,7,1,1,1,1,1),
  ('C1234k','E1',1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
  ('C1212V','E1',1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
  ('C1451k','E2',1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
```

> ```
> Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT 
  `a`.`Total` AS `totalA`, 
  `b`.`Total` AS `totalB`, 
  `a`.`Total`-`b`.`Total` AS `resta`
FROM
  (SELECT 
      `Establecimiento`, 
      `Mes`, 
      SUM(`Col1`+`Col4`+`Col7`+`Col10`) AS `Total`
    FROM `Datos`
    WHERE `Codigo` IN ('A1234k','a1212V','d1451k')
    GROUP BY `Establecimiento`, `Mes`) AS `a`,
  
  (SELECT 
      `Establecimiento`, 
      `Mes`, 
      SUM(`Col2`+`Col3`+`Col11`+`Col15`) AS `Total`
    FROM `Datos`
    WHERE `Codigo` IN ('C1234k','C1212V','C1451k')
    GROUP BY `Establecimiento`, `Mes`) AS `b`;
```

| totalA | totalB | resta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 8 | 34 |
| 48 | 8 | 40 |
| 42 | 4 | 38 |
| 48 | 4 | 44 |

```
SELECT 
    `Establecimiento`, 
    `Mes`, 
    SUM(`Col1`+`Col4`+`Col7`+`Col10`) AS `Total`
FROM `Datos`
WHERE `Codigo` IN ('A1234k','a1212V','d1451k')
GROUP BY `Establecimiento`, `Mes`;
```

| Establecimiento | Mes | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E1 | 1 | 48 |
| E2 | 1 | 42 |

```
SELECT 
    `Establecimiento`, 
    `Mes`, 
    SUM(`Col2`+`Col3`+`Col11`+`Col15`) AS `Total`
FROM `Datos`
WHERE `Codigo` IN ('C1234k','C1212V','C1451k')
GROUP BY `Establecimiento`, `Mes`;
```

| Establecimiento | Mes | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E1 | 1 | 8 |
| E2 | 1 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ydO8Mtt-)

Comment: Lo que estas mostrando es un fallo en tu consulta. Haces un `CROSS JOIN` entre las tablas (en vez de un `INNER JOIN` o `LEFT/FULL OUTER JOIN`) que produce duplicados (join cartesiano). Esto (olvidar de añadir una condición para el join) es un razón porque inventaron los joins explicitos en 1992 y no más usamos el join anticuado con la coma.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner no es un error, es el resultado de los GROUP BY que OP tiene en su consulta inicial. Yo quise poner elementos distintos justamente para hacer notar eso.

Comment: Los resultados son aún más disparatados si agregamos meses distintos, aún con el código de @PatricioMorancho, que ha sido la respuesta aceptada. [Ver fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hgB43oDZ). Creo que hay un error de concepto en el planteamiento de OP.

Comment: Te estas equivocando. El OP muestra dos consultas. Ambos resultan en una fila por Establecimiento y Mes. Consecuentemente, las soluciones en las otras respuestas combinan las filas con el mismo Establecimiento y Mes. Solamente la tuya propone combinar *todas* las filas sin consideración de Establecimiento y Mes. Esto se llama join cartesiano o cross join. Estas usando una sintaxis SQL arcaica que solíamos usar en los anos 1980s. `FROM a , b` es lo mismo que `FROM a CROSS JOIN b` y dice: toma todas las filas de a y combínalas con todas filas de b sin restricción alguna.

Comment: Dos consejos: 1. Elimina esta respuesta. 2. Nunca uses la coma en la cláusula `FROM`.